# Can not add iOS Platform on Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I am trying to:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

However I always receive the following error:

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':CordovaError: Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 3.8.0, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev
    at checkEngines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:116:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:289:16
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 3.8.0, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev
```

This is my `package.json`

```
    {
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-slim": "",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^0.6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-replace-task": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "yargs": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git",
    "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git",
    "https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git",
    "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git",
    "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser",
    "org.apache.cordova.console",
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "org.apache.cordova.statusbar",
    "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen",
    "org.apache.cordova.geolocation",
    "org.apache.cordova.camera",
    "org.apache.cordova.file-transfer",
    "com.ionic.keyboard",
    "./engine/cordova-crosswalk-engine-c0.6.2",
    {
      "locator": "engine/cordova-crosswalk-engine-c0.7.1",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview"
    },
    "https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "locator": "./engine/cordova-android-c0.6.1/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What's your cordova version ?

Comment: 5.0.0 says `cordova info`

Comment: That's strange. Even if this is what config files say there : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/package.json and there : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/plugin.xml, this is actually not taken into account since the last existing version for iOS is 3.8 (https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/releases). I have the save versions and I can add both platforms. But what I don't understand is why do you put your `cordovaPlugins` and `cordovaPlatforms` inside a composer.json. This is not how it's done.

Comment: I am having same issue in my project. any solution @Hendrik?

Comment: @Saifuddin
I have tried this and this helped:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991828/cordova-plugin-whitelist-failed-asking-for-cordova-ios-4

Answer (score 6):

try this, first upgrade all your npm packages (this could take a while)

```
npm update -g
```

Then try to install the platform

```
cordova platform add ios
```

if you still have the problem try removing the platform first (maybe you have already installed it)

```
cordova platform rm ios
```

and then add it again

```
cordova platform add ios
```

you can also try this:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

(from here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS)

Hope this helps

Comment: npm udate -g gave me some errors and warnings, just did npm update without the -g flag (I don't know what the flag is for) and it worked. I could add iOS platform. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a version of whitelist plugin that is compatible with IOS platform 3.8.0, until the 4.0.0 is officially released.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.0.0" />
```